# TFS not updating development Server

Tags: file-upload, tfs, production, staging

We just started using TFS, what's happening is that when a developer modify a code file TFS updates it automatically, but when i go to development server to move files from Development server, files dates are not updated. Is there any easier way of moving files from TFS to staging and production ? or may be any easier way that TFS can update development server automatically?

Comment: Please be more specific. What kind of files are you referring to?

Comment: i am referring to folders that have ASP files, xml, xsl, javascript.

Comment: i move files from Dev to Staging and Production. so the problem is that tfs doesn't update the development files, date and time of those files are not updated with tfs.

Comment: or may be i just need a way how to migrate files from tfs to staging and production.

Comment: Are you judging that this isn't working based on the dates and times?  Or are you actually looking at contents?  Team Foundation Server does not update the timestamps of files to the latest version's date when you do a get.

Comment: we have asp xsl js files in repository so when a dev updates a file in their local machine tfs also updates it, but when i go to our development server to move files those files are not upto date. so there's no connection between tfs and our development , stag , prod server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use MSDeploy to deploy your web application throught the different servers?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465322.aspx